# WSO2 ESB - From VFS to JMS MessageStore

Tags: vfs, wso2-esb

I gotta to receive a file and send it to a jms message store
If I done this using Webservice evrithing work fine but if I try use VFS I recive following exception:

```
[2013-08-21 16:37:45,903] ERROR - VFSTransportListener Error processing File URI : file:///C:/test/myTestInput.txt
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.util.JMSPersistentMessageHelper.getTransportHeaders(JMSPersistentMessageHelper.java:413)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.util.JMSPersistentMessageHelper.createPersistentMessage(JMSPersistentMessageHelper.java:296)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.offer(JMSMessageStore.java:171)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.store.MessageStoreMediator.mediate(MessageStoreMediator.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:162)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:581)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:324)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the related configurations such as proxy services

Comment: It's a know issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2344